# Recommend way to access data file in the app engine python services

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Have a requirement of accessing large pandas data frame files to run some analytics in the worker of the app engine via google cloud tasks

Can somebody please suggest on what component in google cloud can be used for storing and accessing files quickly ?

Any reference to example would be of great help.

Comment: If you don't want to store data in a DB (SQL or NoSQL), then the next option would be to store them in Cloud Storage.

Comment: If the files do not change frequently, you can deploy them with your app and then read them from disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Google Cloud Storage` is the best place to store and accessing the files quickly :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/discover-object-storage-console

`GCS` can store large files and a big amount of files.

You can also use :

- `gsutil` to move or copy files between buckets.
- `Storage transfer service`
  https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview

Your application from `app engine` could use Cloud Storage.